# How to change every character while hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have word

```
<p class="item">Ultimatepp’s</p>
```

I need to change every letter while hovering

I have characters var characters = 'a#ldfhas?

kdjbihoEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS!adfjsd(&?aqdo0ap$dfs@dfqwqrwr'; and i need to insert random character instead of random character in the word Ultimatepp’s.

```
var item = $('.item');
    var arr = Array.from(item);

item.on('mouseenter', function () {
        var characters = 'a#ldfhas?kdjbihoEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS!adfjsd(&?aqdo0ap$dfs@dfqwqrwr';
        var charactersArr = Array.from(characters);
        var self = $(this);
        var itemText = self.html();
        var arr = Array.from(itemText);
        var reversed = arr.reverse();
        var string = reversed.join('');
        var x = charactersArr.splice(Math.random() * itemText.length, itemText.length);
        $(this).html(x);
    });
```

I wrote this code that changes the whole word, but i need to replace characters. Maybe this code could be rewritten?

Comment: What do you mean change every character ? Can you provide some examples of you intended it to be ?

Comment: http://www.kikk.be/2016/
It should be like hover over the navigation "Program" "Schedule" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap each letter in a span so you can bind a separate hover event to each:

```js
var characters = 'a#ldfhas?kdjbihoEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS!adfjsd(&?aqdo0ap$dfs@dfqwqrwr',
    intervalVar,
    timeoutVar;
    intervalCount = 0;

$('.item').html(function() {                                       // this just wraps the original words letters in spans
  var text = $(this).text(),
    html = '';

  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    html += `<span data-original="${text[i]}">${text[i]}</span>`;
  }

  return html;
})                                               
.on('mouseenter', function() {
   var $item = $(this);
   changeChars($item);                              // run immediately when you hover
   setupInterval($item);
})
.on('mouseleave', function() {
  clearInterval(intervalVar);                       // clear interval
  clearTimeout(timeoutVar);                       // clear timeout
  originalChars($(this));                           // reset word
});

function originalChars($elem) {                     // resets word
  var $spans = $elem.children('span');
  $spans.text(function() {
    return $(this).data('original');
  });
  
  return $spans;
}

function setupInterval($elem) {
   clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
   intervalVar = setInterval(function() {           // set new interval to change the characters every second you are hovering
     changeChars($elem);
   }, 200);
}

function changeChars($elem) {
  var $spans = originalChars($elem);                           // reset word before changing again
  var changed = [];
  
  // number of letters to change in original word (up to half of them can change) or change to a constant - eg 4
  var toChange = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($spans.length / 2));
  
  for (i = 0; i < toChange; i++) {                             // change up to a max of toChange characters
    var changing = Math.floor(Math.random() * $spans.length);  // get a random character in the original string
    if (!changed.includes(changing)) {                         // see if it has already been changed
      changed.push(changing);                                  // if not add to list of changed
      $spans.eq(changing).text(characters.substr(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length), 1));  // randomise letter
    }
  }
  
  intervalCount++;
  
  if (intervalCount == 5) {     // add a pause after 5 changes
    intervalCount = 0;
    clearInterval(intervalVar);
    timeoutVar = setTimeout(function() {
      setupInterval($elem);
    }, 1500);  // pause for 1.5 secs before starting loop again
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
}


/* for easier hovering! */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="item">Ultimatepp’s</p>
```

Comment: do font-family:monospace in CSS to avoid the "jump" effect :)

Comment: This works perfectly!) But I need to change not the letter i am hovering.  I need to change a letter randomly. I.e. i hovered over the whole word and letters are changing randomly. Like on this site on the navigation http://www.kikk.be/2016/ . I want to provide the navigation on my site with the same effect

Comment: See update - changes random letters every second you are hovering

Comment: Great!) But it doesn't stops on mouseleave

Comment: @СаняЗоря did you see my final edit - I added a pause in for you (like the other site does)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `mouseenter` event to start a timer that shuffles an array of letters that matches the hovered word, and writes them back to the html. Then the `mouseleave` event would stop the timer would `clearInterval` and set the original text back.

To be able to set the effect on multiple elements, the matching must be done with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and you need to iterate over the matched elements to set the events:

```js
const spans = [...document.querySelectorAll("span")]; //array of spans
const originalTexts = spans.map(span => span.textContent); //original texts
let timer = null;

//forEach to iterate over each span and set the mouseenter event
spans.forEach(span => span.addEventListener("mouseenter", ()=> {
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    let currText = span.textContent.split('');
    //shuffle the word letters
    for (let i = currText.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = currText[i];
        currText[i] = currText[j];
        currText[j] = temp;
    }

    span.textContent = currText.join(''); //set the new word back
  }, 350);
}));

//also iterate to set the mouseleave event
spans.forEach((span, index) => span.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=> {
  if (timer !== null){ 
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  span.textContent = originalTexts[index];
}));
```

```html
<span>Hover Me</span><br>
<span>You can also hover me</span><br>
<span>or me!!</span><br>
```

If you want to randomize according to a characters list you only need to change the *shuffling* part to iterate over each letter and get a random one from the characters:

```js
const characters = 'a#ldfhas?kdjbihoEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS!adfjsd(&?aqdo0ap$dfs@dfqwqrwr';
const spans = [...document.querySelectorAll("span")];
const originalTexts = spans.map(span => span.textContent);
let timer = null;

spans.forEach(span => span.addEventListener("mouseenter", ()=> {
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    let currText = span.textContent.split('');
    //only this part is different now, that randomizes according to the characters
    for (let i = 0; i < currText.length; ++i){
      currText[i] = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
    }
    span.textContent = currText.join('');
  }, 350);
}));

spans.forEach((span, index) => span.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=> {
  if (timer !== null){ 
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  span.textContent = originalTexts[index];
}));
```

```html
<span>Hover Me</span><br>
<span>You can also hover me</span><br>
<span>or me!!</span><br>
```

Comment: I have several nav items and this code works only on first. As far as I understand this is because of querySelector. Can I provide this effect to several nav items? How to insert a letter from this string? var characters = 'a#ldfhas?kdjbihoEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS!adfjsd(&?aqdo0ap$dfs@dfqwqrwr'; but not letters from this word? like on this example http://www.kikk.be/2016/?

Comment: @СаняЗоря Yes it can be used for multiple items but you need to use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over the matched elements. I'll adjust my answer to fit that need